# Click event on dynamically generated image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have image elements that are dynamically generated, each one has a unique name. I need to create a click event that will trigger when an image is clicked and also pass it the name of the image that was clicked.

Comment: `Image` controls, like any `UIElement` subclass, have a `MouseDown` event already, which you can use to detect mouse clicks on the control. As with any of this type of event, the origin element of the event is passed to the event handler already. What more do you need? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried already to solve your issue, along with a precise, clear explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change even handler's signature, and pass something else to the event handler. But you can detect, what image was clicked, by inspecting event arguments:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Image x:Name="Image1" Width="300" Height="200" Source="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-8.jpg" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    <Image x:Name="Image2" Width="300" Height="200" Source="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/car/car-1.jpg" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // writes "Image1" or "Image2", depending on clicked image
        Debug.WriteLine(((Image)e.OriginalSource).Name);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense now, but now how do I dynamically add the `MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"` property to the images dynamically?

Comment: Just like any other event handler: `image.MouseLeftButtonUp += Image_MouseLeftButtonUp;`

Comment: Oh my bad haha, thanks for the reply, I got it now.